# Отображение значений из таблицы в input

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, input

Нужно, чтобы в input отображалось то, что нужно отредактировать, то есть значение из этой таблицы. Не судите, я недавно начал это все изучать..)

```
<?php
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">';
$handle = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'todoshka');
$query = "SELECT id, zd, sod, dat FROM todos WHERE id=$id";
$result = $handle->query($query);
echo '<tr><td>Задача<td align=left><input style="width: 200px;" type="text" name="zd" size=3 ='.$row['zd'].'>';
echo '<tr><td>Содержание задачи<td align=left><input style="width: 200px;" type="text" name="sod" size=3 value='.$row['sod'].'>';
echo '<tr><td>Дата выполнения<td align=left><input style="width: 200px;" type="text" name="dat" size=3 maxlength=3 autocomplete="off" id="dat" value='.$row['dat'].'>';
echo '<tr><td>Статус выполнения<td align=left><select name="stat" style="width: 200px; border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 10px; background-color: white; outline: none;">
        <option>'.$row['stat'].'Готово</option>
        <option>'.$row['stat'].'В процессе</option>
      </select>';
?>
```

Comment: <input value=' . $row['zd'] . ' - все правильно, видимо пустой элемент. Выведи print_r($row);
И если это тестовый код, то посмотри лучше в сторону orm, отделяя вывод html через php.

Comment: @NikitaAbramov Не понимаю при чём тут orm и разделение сущностей шаблон/логика... А вот насчёт input[value] тут согласен